# How to use own data key in victory native instead of x and y which is by default used to draw the chart

Tags: react-native, expo, victory-charts, react-native-svg-charts

How to use own data key in victory native instead of x and y which is by default used to draw the chart
As seen in the below code i want to use myx instead of x to represent data at x-axis and step as y in y-axis.

Instead of this....

```
sampleData=[
  { key:'1',x: 'Jan', y: 5.5, c0: 2,date:'18 Jan 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'2',x: 'Feb', y: 3, c0: 1.5, date:'08 Feb 2019',bank:'Bank Of Baroda',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'3',x: 'March', y: 5, c0: 2 ,date:'19 March 2019',bank:'State Bank of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'4',x: 'Apr', y: 4, c0: 1 ,date:'18 Apr 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'5',x: 'May', y: 6, c0: 2 ,date:'15 May 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'6',x: 'June', y: 2, c0: 4 ,date:'11 June 2019',bank:'Canara Bank',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'7',x: 'July', y: 3, c0: 1 ,date:'28 July 2019',bank:'Punjab National Bank',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
]
```

I want this data is used to the chart....

```
sampleData=[
  { key:'1',myx: 'Jan', step: 5.5, c0: 2,date:'18 Jan 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'2',myx: 'Feb',step: 3, c0: 1.5, date:'08 Feb 2019',bank:'Bank Of Baroda',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'3',myx: 'March', step: 5, c0: 2 ,date:'19 March 2019',bank:'State Bank of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'4',myx: 'Apr', step: 4, c0: 1 ,date:'18 Apr 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'5',myxx: 'May', step: 6, c0: 2 ,date:'15 May 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'6',myx: 'June', step: 2, c0: 4 ,date:'11 June 2019',bank:'Canara Bank',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'7',myx: 'July', step: 3, c0: 1 ,date:'28 July 2019',bank:'Punjab National Bank',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
]
```

In this I want to use myx as a x-axis  data and step as a y- axis data to draw the chart

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
        <VictoryLine
          data={ sampleData }
          y={"step"}
          x={"myx"}
        />
```

You can define your x and y axis by adding those properties